# What is difference between PollableChannel and DirectChannel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Spring Integration is supporting multiple channels.

What is difference among these channel?

Would be appreciate if answer with real world example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can treat a `DirectChannel` as "no channel at all". This one is just a convenient way to meet pipes-and-filters architecture, but support in-memory communication between endpoints, more over in the same thread. On the other hand this is a `SubscribableChannel` which expects some subscribers for sent message dispatching. This is just an implementation details, of course, but still important to know. Also need to keep in mind that with this channel a producer is blocker during send until consumer finishes its work and returns a management to the producer caller back.

A `PolableChannel` is an abstraction. You need to look into the `QueueChannel` implementation. The purpose of this channel do distinguish a sender and receiver for the message in different thread. This model is very close to what we have in Messaging Brokers implementations: the producer sends messages and forgets - it is ready to do anything else meanwhile the message is stored in the queue. The consumers polls the queue periodically for new messages and it does that whenever it is convenient for consumer without any impacts for the producer.

In the real worlds I never used in-memory `QueueChannel`, but its variant based on some persistent storage, in those cases when we couldn't have an access to the Message Broker.
The problem with in-memory that you may lose your data when the application is crashed accidentally.