# Spring Integration DSL Flow - Process one message at a time waiting for the flow to finish before the next message is processed

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a generic Task Service that receives tasks to be executed. It puts the tasks onto a publish-subscribe channel so that the specific implementations that deal with tasks of a particular type will retrieve them from the channel.

I have just had to implement a consumer flow for a particular task type where there has been given a restriction that only one message can be processed at a time, and so I need to configure my flow to some how receive a message and process it, but not receive the next message until that last has been processed. ie. serial processing rather than parallel.

How is this possible with spring integration?

I think I probably need a queue channel receiving from the publish-subscribe channel, then maybe some sort of specially configured poller, but can't really find examples.

The current flow that processes messages as soon as they are received, that needs some modification to process one at a time:

```
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow()
    {
        return from( TaskService.TASKS_CHANNEL_NAME )
            .filter( Task.class, task -> ImportTaskData.TASK_TYPE.equals( task.getTaskType() ) )
            .enrichHeaders( headerEnricher -> headerEnricher.headerExpression( TASK_UUID_HEADER_KEY, "payload.uuid" ) )
            .transform( Task.class, task -> task.getTaskDataAs( ImportTaskData.class ) )
            .enrichHeaders( headerEnricher -> headerEnricher.headerExpression( TASK_RESULTS_DATA_ID_HEADER_KEY, "payload.resultsDataId" ) )
            .transform( Message.class, message -> loadAndTransformImportFile( message ) )
            .transform( Message.class, message -> parseDataRows( message ) )
            .<Pair<Workbook,List<ImportRowData>>>handle( (payload, headers) -> performImport( headers, payload ) )
            .<Pair<Workbook,ImportTaskResults>>handle( (payload, headers) -> processResults( headers, payload ) )
            ;
    }
```

The flow will receive a Task object that is updated in `processResults` with a summary of the results of the task. This Task object is then returned from the flow back to the TaskService to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`ll just make an assumption according to your description and that code snippet you share with us.

It looks like that your `TaskService.TASKS_CHANNEL_NAME` is considered as the mentioned publish-subscribe channel since the next step in this flow is a `filter()` to determine the task type this flow can process.

So, to make it single-threaded and therefore sequential is indeed enough to add a `QueueChannel` just after this `filter()`. Only a requirement is to use a `fixedDelay` for scheduling. It doesn't matter what `maxMessagesPerPoll` you configure since they are going to be pulled from a queue one by one and in the same thread. Looks like the rest of your flow is just direct therefore the next message is going to be processed only if the current one is finished.

Note: the `handle()` with that `GenericHandler` lambda is treated by the framework as a request-reply. So, if that `<Pair<Workbook,ImportTaskResults>>handle()` is indeed the end of the flow be sure you return `null` in the end of your `processResults()`. Otherwise, please, share more info about your logic and what part of your flow(s) should be sequential.

Comment: The flow will receive a Task object that is updated in "processResults" with a summary of the results of the task. This Task object is then returned from the flow back to the TaskService to be saved.

Comment: So, a `TaskService` is like a gateway for your flow (this or other branch according to the `filter()`). Therefore having a `QueueChannel` would be enough for you to achieve a sequential processing.

Comment: I have implemented this approach and it works. I however am facing a problem where some ThreadLocal variables are now lost (Security context and some other custom ones). From what I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727450/what-is-difference-between-pollablechannel-and-directchannel) I understand that the polling consumer is in a different thread. Is this correct, and if so, how best should I resolve propagating the thread locals in this new setup?

Comment: On further inspection it seems it is just the custom ones that are missing and the security ones are there. I think probably due to our setup having a global channel interceptor: SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor. I guess I will have to write something similar for our custom thread local variables?

Comment: Yes, for Security propagation with its standard setup that `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor` is the way to go: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/security.html#security-context-propagation. For a custom `ThreadLocal` indeed you can implement your own `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor`

Comment: I implemented a custom one but it seems that `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` doesn't support multiple instances. I have raised a new question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77058188/2199475

Comment: Yes, thank you for new question. Will look tomorrow