# Multiple ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptors not possible

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a Spring Integration setup where I have configured a `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor` which propagates the spring security context async channel boundaries. This works well.

I also have some custom ThreadLocal data in addition to the security ThreadLocal context data that I would like to propagate too. I have implemented a custom `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` in a similar manner to how the `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor` is implemented, but I have discovered that it is not possible to have more than one `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` as it implements a `MessageWithThreadState` that has one state object. This state object is the value stored by the first `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` registered and so the second `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` instance which wants to register different data gets a ClassCastException.

What is a better way to propagate this custom data as it seems the `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` is not designed to have more than one piece of state?

```
2023-09-07 09:51:16,643 [task-scheduler-6] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class com....origin.OriginData (org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and com....origin.OriginData are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @3070f3e6)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:347)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class com....origin.OriginData (org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and com....origin.OriginData are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @3070f3e6)
    at com....origin.OriginDataPropagationChannelInterceptor.populatePropagatedContext(OriginDataPropagationChannelInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor.postReceive(ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.postReceive(AbstractMessageChannel.java:522)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.receive(AbstractPollableChannel.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.receiveMessage(PollingConsumer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:443)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: The exception you are sharing with us has nothing to do with the mentioned `MessageWithThreadState`. It feels like you use the same `ThreadLocal` variable for both use-cases. I wonder if you can share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have a confirmation that this is a problem.
And here is the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/8735.

Essentially, you are right: when we use several `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` instances in the same channel, we got the problem restoring contexts populated by them. Just because they are stacking their states, but they are still called from the channel in the order they are provided.

As a workaround I suggest to look into intercepting different channels: do not use them in the same channel. Or implement a composite thread state to take both values into a single container and then restore them respectively.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue. In the end I realised that the state data we have could just be passed in the message headers and then extracted into the ThreadLocal variables. So I implemented an ExecutorInterceptor to extract from the thread local variable, add to the message header, then in the new thread extract from the message header and put back into the thread local variable

Comment: I think this is the best solution to keep the system stateless: even if we send same message to different consumers, they still will be able to extract an info from header without affecting other consumers.